# LINQ join with a literal values

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

This is kind of hypothetical as I'm thinking about how to design this.  Consider this query with some literal integer values in the join criteria:

```
Select * 
From LeftPeople l
Inner Join RightPeople r On r.RecordId = l.RecordId and r.ResultId = 3 and l.ResultId = 7
```

Would this be the correct equivilant in LINQ?  It seems kind of a cludge if this would even work and am wondering if there's a better way.  I suppose I could put it in the where criteria instead.  What do you think?

```
 var query = from leftPerson in LeftPeople
   join rightPerson in RightPeople on 
   new { RecordId = leftPerson.RecordId, RightResultId = 3,  LeftResultId = leftPerson.ResultId }
   equals new { RecordId = rightPerson.recordid, RightResultId = rightPerson.ResultId ,  LeftResultId = 7 }
   select new { LeftPerson = leftPerson, RightPerson = rightPerson };
```

Comment: If this is LINQ to Entities, per your tags, [you shouldn't be using `join` at all](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/).

Comment: Good information, but in the context of what I am doing there isn't a clean way to create an association to represent this relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want items with a RightResultId of 3, then use a Where clause to filter out others. I don't think this really belongs in a join clause. It may work, but it feels messy to me.

In other words, I would do:

```
var query = from left in LeftPeople
            where left.RightResultId = 3
            join right in RightPeople.Where(r => r.LeftResultId = 7)
            on left.RecordId equals right.RecordId
            select new { LeftPerson = left, RightPerson = right };
```

That's assuming that `RecordId` is really the primary key here.

Comment: +1 This query definitely matches the underlying SQL better but just out of curiosity, when would the result of the query you posted here differ from the result of the query in my answer?

Comment: @Justin: Assuming you add a select clause so that it's a valid query expression, I'd expect the results to be the same :) I generally favour narrowing a query before the join - it just feels neater. I'd expect a decent query optimizer to make it work the same way in SQL - although in LINQ to Objects my form would definitely be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The filter for LeftPeople.ResultId and RightPeople.ResultId belong in the Where clause in your LINQ statement:

```
var query = from l in LefPeople
            join r in RightPeople on l.RecordId equals r.ResultId
            where r.ResultId == 3 && l.ResultId == 7
            select new { LeftPerson = l, RightPerson = r };
```

Trying to shoehorn them into the Join clause will only make your query harder to read/understand.

That said, I would probably argue that the SQL Query should have those filters in the WHERE clause as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you made an association, you could write:

```
from left in leftPeople
where left.ResultId == 7
from right in left.RightPeople
where right.ResultId == 3
select new {left, right};
```